# Shared /opt between distros

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, acl

I have currently sat opp a Workstation where I'm using the filesystem /opt/vm to store my various virtual machines, nothing else, no binaries or config files. This filesystem is mounted to a dedicated disk/partition with nothing else on.

I plan to share this filesystem between different distros which I install on the same machine. The idea is to conserve all my VMs without need to backing them up before I reinstall, or any need to duplicate VMs so they are reachable independent of the distro I boot up.

Any special considerations I need to take into account?

∕A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one:

The `/opt` is currently used by many commercial (and free) products, which do not like to spread its files over `/usr` tree. So majority of system administrators would expect to see `/opt/oracle`, `/opt/nodejs`, etc. It would be a huge surprise to have something mounted into the `/opt`.
The tradition is to mount external stores into `/mnt`.

So if you are not afraid that your colleges and future admins curse you for a breaking traditions and doing something unexpected - go for it.

Comment: If the VMs are all neatly under `/opt/vm`, I don't think much cursing is in order at all - with modern versions of Oracle, a request for a filesystem of 50-100 GB for Oracle binaries (e.g. at `/opt/oracle`) is not exactly uncommon.

Comment: Still, it is as easy and more traditional to put them into `/mtn/vm` and just point the "default vm location" there. If really needed, it is possible to create a symlink from `/opt/vm` to `/mnt/vm`. But the whole idea to "share something" calls for the use of NAS for storage and sharing from the NAS.